# Cardinal number of the Banach space $c_0(A)$

Tags: set-theory, banach-spaces, cardinals

For infinite dimensional Banach space $X$, the cardinality of $X$ is equal to its algebraic dimension.
Now let $A$ be an infinite set and define $c_0(A)=\{f:A\rightarrow\Bbb R, f$ is bounded and $ \lim_{x\in A}f(x)=0\}.$
We know that $c_0(A)$ is a Banach space with $\|.\|_{\infty}$. Now, what is the algebraic dimension of $c_0(A)?$ (or equivalently, what is the cardinality of $c_0(A)$)

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{x \in A}$?

Comment: If $A$ is a set, what $\lim_{x\in A}f(x)$

Comment: (For an infinite set $A$,)  $\lim_{x\in A}f(x)=0$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite subset $F\subseteq A$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon $ for all $x\in A-F.$

Comment: There are a few cases we can knock off immediately. You've already observed that if $|A|\leq\aleph_0$ then $|c_0(A)|=\mathfrak{c}$. This is actually true whenever $|A|\leq\mathfrak{c}$. Indeed, we can identify $c_0(A)$ with a subset of $(\mathbb{R}\times A)^\mathbb{N}$ so that, in this case, $\mathfrak{c}\leq|c_0(A)|\leq(\mathfrak{c}\cdot\mathfrak{c})^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$. A similar argument can be used to show that if $|A|=\kappa^+$ for some $\kappa\geq\mathfrak{c}$ then $\kappa^+\leq|c_0(A)|\leq 2^\kappa$. Under GCH, this means $|c_0(A)|=|A|$ whenever $|A|$ is a successor cardinal.

Comment: Another observation:  If $|A|=2^\kappa$ for some $\kappa\geq\aleph_0$ then $|c_0(A)|=|A|$, even without GCH.  This makes me strongly suspect that $|c_0(A)|=\max\{\mathfrak{c},|A|\}$ for all $A$.

Comment: Okay, the answer is $\max\{\mathfrak{c},|A|^{\aleph_0}\}$.  See here for details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117794/what-is-the-cardinality-or-algebraic-dimension-of-a-hilbert-space-over-a-cardi