# what is the cardinality (or algebraic dimension) of a hilbert space over a cardinal $\kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, hilbert-spaces, cardinals

Something has been bugging me lately; maybe you guys can help satisfy my curiosity.

Let $\kappa$ denote any nonzero cardinal.  For convenience, we identify $\kappa$ with its smallest ordinal representation.  By "a (real) Hilbert space over $\kappa$" we mean a Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis of dimension $\kappa$, which we will represent as the space
$$\ell_2(\kappa)=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^\kappa:\sum_{\alpha\in\kappa}|x_\alpha|^2<\infty\right\}$$
endowed with the $\ell_2$-norm.  Equivalently, $\ell_2(\kappa)$ is the $\ell_2$-closed linear span of unit vectors $(e_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\kappa}$ in $\mathbb{R}^\kappa$.

When $\kappa\leq\mathfrak{c}$, we obtain that $|\ell_2(\kappa)|=\mathfrak{c}$, and when $\kappa=2^\lambda$ for some $\lambda>\aleph_0$ we have $|\ell_2(\kappa)|=\kappa$.  However, the general case eludes me, and so I ask the following.

**Question 1.**  What is the cardinality of $\ell_2(\kappa)$?

Since algebraic dimension coincides with cardinality in the remaining cases, we could simply ask for that:

**Question 2.** What is the algebraic dimension of $\ell_2(\kappa)$ when $\kappa>\mathfrak{c}$?

It is clear that we can identify $\ell_2(\kappa)$ with a subset of $(\mathbb{R}\times\kappa)^\mathbb{N}$, so that $|\ell_2(\kappa)|\leq\kappa^{\aleph_0}$.

This question isn't important or anything, but I was curious about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$, with more possibly being known based on the value of $\kappa$ and the background set-theoretic assumptions.

---

It's not hard to show that in fact $\vert l_2(\kappa)\vert=\kappa^{\aleph_0}$; you've already got one half (the upper bound), and for the other half given an $f:\omega\rightarrow\kappa$ let $x_\alpha=2^{-f^{-1}(\alpha)}$ for $\alpha\in ran(f)$ and $x_\alpha=0$ otherwise.

However, *even in the presence of GCH* this isn't generally simplifiable *(contra your sentence beginning "Under GCH ...")*! [Konig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) implies for example that $(\aleph_\omega)^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_\omega$ even if GCH holds. More generally we'll see something interesting happen whenever $\kappa$ has **countable cofinality**; GCH rules out interesting things happening in all *other* cases.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I was assuming that $\kappa$ was a successor cardinal (is it right that $\beta^+$ is always equal to $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for some $\alpha$?) when I worked out the argument, in which case I believe we really do get $|\ell_2(\kappa)|=\kappa$ under GCH.  But the limit cardinals are different apparently.  Thanks!

Comment: @BenW Yes, if $\kappa$ is a successor then you're fine. Even singular cardinals *in general* aren't a problem - it's specifically *countable cofinality* that's at issue here.

Comment: The case $\aleph_0=cf(k)<k$ also comes up in the Q of whether a metric  space in which any dense subset has  cardinality $k$ or more, has a closed discrete topological subspace of cardinality $k.$